# Sql query to search for multiple match in junction table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, yii, yii2

[image]

Hello, I have two tables and one junction table. And I want to find all estates, that has one or multiple comforts. I wrote this query (postrgreSql):

```
SELECT DISTINCT "estates".*
FROM   "estates"
       LEFT JOIN "estate_comforts"
              ON "estates"."id" = "estate_comforts"."estate_id"
WHERE  "estate_comforts"."comfort_id" IN ( '1', '2' )
```

It finding estates that has the first comfort OR the second, but I need to search in "AND" mode.

[image]

This project using Yii2 framewors, so plain sql or ActiveRecord statement are acceptable.

**Update**. This query select all esates, regardless of the comforts

```
SELECT DISTINCT "estates".*
FROM   "estates"
       LEFT JOIN "estate_comforts"
              ON "estates"."id" = "estate_comforts"."estate_id"
AND "estate_comforts"."comfort_id" IN ( '1', '2' )
```

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and Postgresql here? Please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Nope, i'am using yii2 ActiveRecord with Postgres and copy query from the log. I can give code, than generates this query, but is it necessary?

Comment: Skip the WHERE clause, do `AND "estate_comforts"."comfort_id" IN ( '1', '2' )` to  get true left join behavior!

Comment: This query select all esates, regardless of the comforts, or may be i have a typo?

Comment: Can't you add a few rows of sample data for each table, and the expected result?

Comment: Added. From this example, my query get all estates, cause third estate has one of needed comfort. And your query gets all estates, regardless of the comforts. I want to get just first two, cause only they have two comforts together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either `JOIN` estate_comforts twice, one time for comfort_id 1, and another time for comfort_id 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "estates".*
FROM   "estates"
   INNER JOIN "estate_comforts" ec1
          ON "estates"."id" = ec1."estate_id"
   INNER JOIN "estate_comforts" ec2
          ON "estates"."id" = ec2."estate_id"
WHERE ec1."comfort_id" = '1'
  AND ec2."comfort_id" = '2'
```

Alternatively, do a `GROUP BY` on estate_comforts to find estate_id with at least two different comfort_id values. Join with that result:

```
select e.*
from "estates" e
  join (select "estate_id"
        from "estate_comforts"
        WHERE  "comfort_id" IN ( '1', '2' ) 
        group by "estate_id"
        having count(distinct "comfort_id") >= 2) ec ON e."id" = ec."estate_id"
```

Comment: Second query dont work as expected. First of all, there's no `estate_id` field in `estates` table, so it gives error `Unknown column 'e.estate_id' in 'on clause'`, but if change it to `id`, query give me all estates, regardless the comforts.

Comment: Sorry, was meant to return all estates with at least two different comfort_id, no matter which ones. Added a WHERE.